# Linux mint 17 doesn't start after hibernating

Tags: linux-mint, hibernate

So here is my trouble - i put my laptop with Linux Mint 17 to hibernation and after i decided to resume session i see only a black screen so i am now to start in recovery mode. I don't need to restore that session - i just want to get my Linux back to work. What is the way to edit GRUB loading script to just start new session? Now it looks like [this](http://www.screencast.com/t/bwTtPOgVdzp5)

I also moved a RESUME file from `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/` - still no luck - got black screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your hardware?

Comment: It is Acer Aspire V3-772G. Cannot show output of inxi right now because i left laptop at home.

Comment: There we go! Here is output of inxi -Fxz - https://imageshack.com/i/eyxPocuCp and blkid -o list - https://imageshack.com/i/pdZfQKy4p

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was editing the file `/etc/rc.local`. Now that file looks like:

```
#My laptop have three USB ports
echo USB0 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo USB1 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo USB2 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup

exit 0
```

> ...it disables only the monitorization of those ports during
>   suspension/hibernation.[[1](http://forum.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=125375)]